# makeStyles show a div when hovering over nested a link

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So I am trying to show a div box when a user hovers over the link.

For example:
Say I have an image inside the a href I want a div to float above that and say click here.

React Style code.

```
a: {

    '& :hover':{
        '& div#show':{
          display:'block'
        }
    }
  },
```

React code
    
                  
                  
                  Stuff shown on hover

Full code

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles,styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
//import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Container, Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import comedynight from '../images/shows/PrideInjulyFridaynightcomedy2020.png';
import dragnight from '../images/shows/PrideInjulySaturdaynightDrag2020.png';


const drawerWidth = 240;
const DonateButton = styled(Button)({
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  width: '100%',
  fontWeight: 'Bold',
  padding: '0 30px',
});


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
  a: {

    '& :hover':{
        '& div#show':{
          display:'block'
        }
    }
  },
}));


export default function Home() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open] = React.useState(false);



    return(
        <Container>
        <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })}
      >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item lg={12}>
              <DonateButton>Click here to donate now to support WAAids Council</DonateButton>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={6}>
              <a href="/shows/comedy" alt="Friday Comedy Night" className={classes.a}>
              <img src={comedynight} alt="Friday Night Comedy" style={{width:"100%"}}/>
              </a>
              <div id="show" style={{display:'none'}}>Stuff shown on hover</div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={6}>
            <img src={dragnight} alt="Saturday Night Drag" style={{width:"100%"}}/>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </main>
      </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: why don't you go with states to show and hide that div?

Comment: @AdeshKumar how would I do this never used states for that before.

Comment: hey you have used hooks to edit state. simply use a state make it true/false on element hover. while its true show the did else hide it

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using state, but if you want to make it with css then you can use it like this

```
a + #show: {
    display: 'none'
}
a:hover + #show: {
    display: 'block'
}
```

Comment: I copied and paste your answer and sadly it throw errors

Comment: i updated my answer, please check and try to use this

Comment: and remove inline style from
<div id="show" style={{display:'none'}}>Stuff shown on hover</div>

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question (`'& div#show'`) doesn't work because you are using a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) instead of a sibling selector and the `div` is not a descendant of the link. Also, `display: "none"` needs to be in the [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.1.1) (within the styles passed to `makeStyles`). If you instead do it in inline styles (as you currently have it), the inline styles will win over the CSS classes generated by JSS because inline styles have higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Below is an example of using an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) in JSS. This is using another class for the toggled element rather than using an id, see my second example if you want to continue using an id.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  triggerElement: {
    "&:hover + $toggledElement": {
      backgroundColor: "#ccc",
      display: "block"
    }
  },
  toggledElement: {
    display: "none"
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.triggerElement}>
        This is the trigger element. Hover over this to see the toggled element.
      </div>
      <div className={classes.toggledElement}>This is the toggled element</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Sibling selector JSS]

Here is another example based more closely on your existing code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  a: {
    "& + #show": {
      display: "none"
    },
    "&:hover + #show": {
      backgroundColor: "#ccc",
      display: "block"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/shows/comedy" className={classes.a}>
        Friday Night Comedy
      </a>
      <div id="show">Stuff shown on hover</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Sibling selector JSS]